# Bind UDP socket to a specific local endpoint

Tags: c#, .net, windows, sockets

I do this:

```
Socket socket = new Socket(SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
socket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(new IPAddress(new byte[] {192, 168, 1, 8}), 45678));
socket.BeginConnect(new IPEndPoint(new IPAddress(new byte[] { 65, 52, 108, 52 }), 80), null, null);
socket.Send(new byte[] { 1, 2, 3 });
```

but the socket is not actually bind to local IP address 192.168.1.8, just the port:

```
UDP    0.0.0.0:45678          *:*
```

Why?

Answer (score 0):

I used the wrong overloaded constructor for the socket:

```
Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
socket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(new IPAddress(new byte[] {192, 168, 1, 8}), 45678));
socket.BeginConnect(new IPEndPoint(new IPAddress(new byte[] { 65, 52, 108, 52 }), 80), null, null);
socket.Send(new byte[] { 1, 2, 3 });
```

Now it is correctly bind:

```
 UDP    192.168.1.8:45678      *:*
```